# Problems with adding shader

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I wrote a shader and want to test it on codepen. Now I have no errors in console, but it still doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my vertex shader.

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="shader">

void main() {
  vUv = (uModel * vec3(position.xy, 1.)).xy;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
```

And fragment shader

```
<script id="fragmentShader" type="shader">
uniform vec2 uResolution;
uniform sampler2D uTexture1;
varying vec2 vUv;
  uniform mat3 uModel;
  varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    vec2 position = gl_FragCoord.xy / uResolution;

    float ratio = 0.3;
    float progress = .3;

    float layer1L = abs(step(.3, position.x) - 1.);
    float layer1R = step(.7, position.x);
    float layer2L = abs(step(.1, position.x) - 1.);
    float layer2R = step(.9, position.x);
    float layer3L = abs(step(.06, position.x) - 1.);
    float layer3R = step(.94, position.x);
    float layer4L = abs(step(.02, position.x) - 1.);
    float layer4R = step(.98, position.x);

    // texture A
    float dx1 = 0.;
    dx1 += layer1L * .5 * ratio;
    dx1 -= layer1R * .5 * ratio;
    dx1 += layer2L * .25 * ratio;
    dx1 -= layer2R * .25 * ratio;
    dx1 += layer3L * .1 * ratio;
    dx1 -= layer3R * .1 * ratio;
    dx1 += layer4L * .06 * ratio;
    dx1 -= layer4R * .06 * ratio;

    vec4 texA = texture2D(uTexture1, vec2(vUv.x + dx1, vUv.y));

    vec4 fcolor = texA;

    gl_FragColor = fcolor;
}
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/nadjakoroleva/pen/Vgdjdx

Comment: Comment out the line: `var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({  map: tex,});`, thus you'll apply your shader material instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for the information you included with your question. As a suggestion for future questions, consider creating a [`Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using [snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). By keeping all the code in your question, it will prevent losing context when (_not if_) your codepen is deleted or the URL changes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're creating a `Mesh` with two materials.

`var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material2, material );`

The third argument `material` is essentially doing nothing, so everything you do in the vertex & fragment shaders is not being displayed. You need to pass only your `ShaderMaterial` into the Mesh constructor to see the results:

`var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );`